# Flink on K8S: how do I provide Flink configuration to the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am following [Flink Kubernetes Setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html) to create a cluster, but it is unclear how can I provide [Flink configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html) to the cluster? e.g., I want to specify `jobmanager.heap.size=2048m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, all configuration has to be passed via a yaml configuration file.

It seems that `jobmanager.heap.size` is a common option that can be configured.

That being said, the approach on kubernetes is a little different when it comes to providing this configuration file.

The next piece of the puzzle is figuring out what the current start command is for the container you are trying to launch.  I assumed you were using the [official flink docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/flink) which is good because the Dockerfile is opensource (link to repo at the bottom).  They are using a complicated script to launch the flink container, but if you dig through that script you will see that it's reading the configuration yaml from `/opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`. Instead of trying to change this, it'll probably be easier to just mount a yaml file at that exact path in the pod with your configuration values.

Here's the [github repo that has these Dockerfiles for reference](https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink).

Next question is what should the yaml file look like?
From their docs:

> All configuration is done in conf/flink-conf.yaml, which is expected
>   to be a flat collection of YAML key value pairs with format key: value.

So, I'd imagine you'd create `flink-conf.yaml` with the following contents:

```
jobmanager.heap.size: 2048m
```

And then mount it in your kubernetes pod at `/opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml` and it should work.

From a kubernetes perspective, it might make the most sense to make a configmap of that yaml file, and mount the config map in your pod as a file.  [See reference docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Specifically, you are most interested in [creating a configmap from a file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) and [Adding a config map as a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)

Lastly, I'll call this out but I won't recommend it because of the fact that the owners of flink have marked it as an incubating feature currently, they have started providing a [helm chart for Flink](https://github.com/docker-flink/examples), and I can see that they are passing `flink-conf.yaml` as a config map in the [helm chart templates](https://github.com/docker-flink/examples/blob/master/helm/flink/templates/configmap-flink.yaml#L8-L17) (ignore values surrounded with `{{ }}` - that is helm template syntax). Here is where they [mount their config map into a pod](https://github.com/docker-flink/examples/blob/master/helm/flink/templates/deployment-jobmanager.yaml#L42-L44).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, I learned a lot from it.